# Terminal Minecraft server autosave script

Tags: bash

This is a follow up to an earlier question about a terminal script for Minecraft that will start up a server with 1 gigabyte of ram, and promptly begin a 30 minute loop that will make frequent backups of the server map.

This is the code I'm currently working with:

```
cd /Users/userme/Desktop/Minecraft
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar & bash -c 'while [ 0 ]; do cp -r /Users/userme/Desktop/Minecraft/world /Users/userme/Desktop/A ;sleep 1800;done'
```

Now obviously, this loop will save the backups in directory "A" with the name "world". Is there a modification I can make to this code so that it basically counts the amount of loops the script makes, and then applies that count to the end of the backups. For example, `world5`, or `world 12`. A modification that can get rid of old backups would be nice as well.

Comment: a specific reason why you'd want all that in 1 line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I broke it down into separate lines for better readability:

If you want to put it back all into one line, you can add the `;` back in where appropriate

```
counter=1
while [ 0 ] 
do 
    if [ -e /Users/userme/Desktop/A/world"$counter" ]; then
        rm -f /Users/userme/Desktop/A/world"$counter"
    fi
    counter=$((counter+1))
    cp -r /Users/userme/Desktop/Minecraft/world /Users/userme/Desktop/A/world"$counter" 
    sleep 1800
done
```

Comment: This worked very well! Instead of using a ; though, I just went with an ampersand to run it in the background while simultaneously launching the server.jar. Thanks!